# Error Correcting Code

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

In my Linear Algebra book I have a chapter about error correcting code.

there is an example involving  Redundancy in the form of a check digit :

we have $white=(0,0)$, $red=(1,0)$, $blue=(0,1)$, $yellow=(1,1)$.........        $13.13$

Since our digit are elements of $\mathbb{F}_{2}$ we have it 
$white=(0,0,0)$, $red=(1,0,1)$, $blue=(0,1,1)$, $yellow=(1,1,0)$

I understood what the book has done here. Then they add greater redundancy in the following way ( which I do not understand it ): if $w$ is one of the four pairs of $13.13$, follow $w$ with a check digit and then with $w$ again. Thus,

$(0,0) \rightarrow (0,0,0,0,0),(1,0) \rightarrow (1,0,1,1,0)$

$(0,1) \rightarrow (0,1,1,0,1),(1,1) \rightarrow (1,1,0,1,1)$

would someone please help me out understanding what they have done here.

Comment: usually repeating the message greatly enhances your degree of verification, you are then able to detect errors in any bit, as long as they have not been simultaneously flipped, and then passing the check digit gives an idea about how to correct it properly.

Comment: Thank you! but I did not get how they come up with $ (0,0,0,0,0),(1,0) \rightarrow (1,0,1,1,0)$

Answer (score 2):

One linear formula they could have applied:

if the colour is $(a,b)$ we make the redundant copy $(a,b,a+b,a,b)$ where we add a new coordinate which is the sum of the previous 2 (and as we work in $\mathbb{F}_2$, $b + a + b = a$ and $a+b + a = b$). So we add literal checksums to the original data.

The original data of length 2 had the property that if one bit flipped, we would get a valid alternative and no way to detect it.

Now if we flip a bit in the sent word $(1,0) \rightarrow (1,0,1,1,0)$ and say the second bit flips, we receive $(1,1,1,1,0)$. This has Hamming distance (the number of differences) distance 1 to a correct possible word and the distance to the other words $(0,0,0,0,0)$ is 4, $(0,1,1,0,1)$ is 3, and $(1,1,0,1,1)$ is 2. So the likeliest sent word was the one with the smallest distance, and we correctly decode to $(1,0)$ despite the one bit flip. Two flips could lead to new errors.

Answer (score 0):

They seem to be using *parity* to construct an error correcting code. That is, if you have an odd number of $1$s, then set the special bit called as the "parity bit" to $1$. However, if there are even number of $1$s, then set the parity bit to 0.

For example,

$(0, 0)$ has no $1$. Hence, $(0, 0) \to (0, 0, 0)$ where the third bit is the **parity bit**.

The general pattern of a message encoding seems to be $$(b_0, b_1, p, b_0, b_1)$$

Where $b_0, b_1$ are the information bits, and $p$ is the parity bit.

$(0, 0)$ has 0 repetitions of 1. hence, $p = 0$ since the number of 1's is even.

$$(0, 0) \to (0, 0, 0, 0, 0)$$

$(1, 1)$  has 2 repetitions of 1, which is even. So, $p=0$ since the number of 1's is even (2 1's).

$$(1, 1) \to (1, 1, 0, 1, 1)$$

$(1, 0)$ has 1 repetition of 1, and is hence odd. Hence, $p = 1$

$$(1, 0) \to (1, 0, 1, 1, 0)$$

One way to think of the value of the parity bit is the XOR for all values in your tuple. Hence, for example,
$$p((0, 0)) = 0 \oplus 0 = 0$$
$$p((1, 0)) = 1 \oplus 0 = 1$$
$$p((1, 1)) = 1 \oplus 1 = 1$$

Since you mentioned Field theory, XOR is the same as addition in $\mathbb{F}_2$.